# When document.defaultView becomes null?

Tags: javascript, dom

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/defaultView) describes `Document.defaultView` as

> In browsers, document.defaultView returns the window object associated with a document, or null if none is available.

However, how can it be null?
These are my questions.

1. What is the situation of *"none is available"* ?
2. Is it possible to exist *detached* `document` from `window`?
3. Is It possible to exist `window` without `document`?

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#concept-document-bc

Comment: @Bravo Thanks, I got the hang of it somewhat. I'll get deep into browsing context. I couldn't notice beyond `window`.